# (intermediate value).setTween is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I am a noob to using scrollmagic and trying to learn by replicating one of the examples of ScrollMagic. http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/advanced_tweening.html

In order to load scrollmagic and greensocks javascript library, I added these scripts below. However, in the console, it says .setTween is not a function.. How can I load these scripts successfully? Arent they in a right order?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/jquery.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: For me using uncompressed version of libraries gave me the detail I needed, found the tip here: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/296#issuecomment-94143789

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that you missed this one?

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.velocity.min.js